# Get element index for prev/next button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to finish a slider for a gallery of images and all I'm missing is the prev/next button functionality. Right now the prev button is working but there's one issue. Here's the problem, I have a gallery of images, when I click on them a popup shows up displaying the image that was clicked. However, if I click any image that isn't the first one of the array and click the prev button, it's gonna take me all they way back to the last image of the array, instead the prev button should take me to the image previous to the one that was clicked.

So if I have 10 images, and I click the one with index of 3 in the array and click the previous button, the popup should show the image with index of 2. Let me show you what I got so far:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-2.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-3.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-4.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-5.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-6.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-7.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-8.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-9.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-10.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-11.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-12.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
</div>
```

This is the Js:

```
const overlayString = () => `
<div class="overlay">
  <button class="overlay__close-icon" id="closeOverlay">&times;</button>
  <img src="img/prev.png" alt="Previous button" class="overlay__btn" id="overlayPrev">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="overlay__img">
  <img src="img/next.png" alt="Next button" class="overlay__btn" id="overlayNext">
</div>`;

// Inject template to html structure
document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', overlayString());

// Replace overlay img
const overlay = img => document.querySelector('.overlay__img').src = img.src;

// Show elements based on section
let query = document.querySelector('.gallery');
let images = 'gallery__img';
if (!query) {
  query = document.querySelector('.section-gallery');
  images = 'section-' + images;
}

// Nodelist elements
const imageElems = document.querySelectorAll("." + images);
let currentOverlay;

// Open overlay
query.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('showOverlay');
  document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden';

// Change overlay img based on the element that was clicked.
    const target = event.target;
    const index =  Array.prototype.indexOf.call(query.children, target);
    overlay(imageElems[index]);
});

// Overlay prev and next button
document.querySelector('#overlayPrev').addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentOverlay > 0 ? --currentOverlay : currentOverlay = imageElems.length - 1;
  overlay(imageElems[currentOverlay])
});
```

I know that when I click on the prev button my code is not registering the index of the element that was clicked and that's probably the reason of why this is it not working as I want, but I'm a stuck here, any help is greatly appreciated.

No jQuery please, I am trying to do this only with pure JS.

Comment: There is no element with an `id` of `"main"`.

Comment: <main id="main"></main> tag is wrapping all the content of my html structure except for the header and footer.

Comment: Is my answer what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a querySelector to get all of the images and you use `forEach` to iterate through its elements and attach an event listener that will output the index of the image in the nodeList or `Array.prototype.indexOf.call` to get the index of the image in the nodeList. If you want to get the element's index starting from one, just add one to the index in the event listener.

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-2.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-3.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-4.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-5.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-6.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-7.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-8.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-9.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-10.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-11.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
  <img src="img/hg-12.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
</div>
<script>
var galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll("div.gallery > .gallery__img");
galleryImages.forEach((img, index)=>{
 img.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   console.log("Index of image: "+index);
   //console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(galleryImages, e.target));
  });
});
</script>
```